# WS02 ESB GREG: remote instance and mount configuration in a cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

in my lab I have this setup between an ESB 4.9.0 and a GREG 5.2.0

```
<dbConfig name="remote_registry">
      <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB_GREG</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://y.y.y.46:9445/registry">
    <id>gregid</id>
    <dbConfig>remote_registry</dbConfig>
    <cacheId>regadmin@jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.45:3306/governancedb</cacheId>
        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governace" overwrite="true">
     <instanceId>gregid</instanceId>
     <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Now I have created two cluster, the GREG one (with a LB in front greg.my.cluster) and a MGR (mgt-esb.my.cluster) and two workers ( esb.my.cluster)

My question is: how to configure the ESB instances ?
I assume that

`<remoteInstance url="https://y.y.y.46:9445/registry">`

becomes

`<remoteInstance url="https://greg.my.cluster/registry">`

but where to put it ?
Shall I reproduce that conf only on the ESB MGR ? Only on the the workers ? Or on the three of them ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a JDBC mount, `remoteInstance` should be set as the hostname value in the carbon.xml file.

As an example, if you have defined the hostname as governance.wso2.com and the server is running with 2 port offset, the `remoteInstance` URL should be:

```
<remoteInstance url="https://governance.wso2.com:9445/registry">
```

Comment: May you also answer the main question?

Comment: This remoteInstance is a must for G-Reg nodes. However it is better to have it configured for both esb mgt and worker nodes.